# What is the specific meaning of 時の函 in this song lyric?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics, song

I came across a song (琥珀ト瑠璃ノ輪舞曲) where there's a line

> "時の函に横たわっていた".

I know the meaning of the words individually ,

> "時の" = of a certain time,
> "函" = box,
> "横たわる" = lying down /stretching out.

But putting them to together in the sentence makes no sense to me.
The most literal way I can translate it is "Lying in a box of a certain time" But the meaning seems incomplete to me. Is there any other meaning behind it?
Thank you!

For context, these are the song lines before it :

> 煤けた硝子玉 淡い月と碧い夜
> それだけを映して時の函に横たわっていた

Comment: 時の函 is most probably *box of time* and you can totally be lying on it.

Comment: I see, thank you! I guess I'm just having some trouble trying to visualise it. I'm not sure what "box of time" even means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal translation is:

> 時の函に横たわっていた
> [I] was lying in the box of time

Judging from [the broader context](https://utaten.com/lyric/mi18112254/), this is the author's own poetic way of saying "(I) have spent a long time lying in this box". This 函 primarily refers to the "frame of time", but I guess it's also a reference to a physical storage box. Note that the character ("I") in this song is a half-forgotten and half-broken windup doll who has been waiting for a new owner for a long time. 煤けた硝子玉 refers to his own glass eyes.

Comment: Thank you so much!!